# Animate the Sun's true motion through the sky?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm experimenting with the Sun, skies and atmospheres in Blender and I'm looking for a way to accurately animate the Sun's motion through the sky from sunrise to sunset.

The Sun Position addon works great for setting the position of the Sun for a moment in time, but I see no way to animate its natural arc though the sky. Can this be done? Thanks. Blender 3.0, Windows 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set keyframes for the time and day parameters of the [Sun Position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/lighting/sun_position.html) by right clicking on them:

[image: Sun Position settings highlighting time and date]

You find these settings in the World tab of the properties editor. The manual entry has more details on how to coordinate the Sun with and HDR, et cetera.

Comment: Marty Fouts, very cool! Thanks!

Comment: @WilburPost  If that works, maybe click the arrow and accept the answer?

Comment: sure thing. I didn't realize that's how it works here. :)

Comment: This is only practical for one day, though. If I want a complete year, that does not work.